# RxJava onErrorResumeNext and onError issue

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

In my application, I make a request to the server to get some data. I realised it via retrofit and rxjava. Also, I made data caching via Realm database. If error occurs, data loads from database.
So, about the problem. When I make a success request, and only then make an error request (for example enabling aeroplane mode on my device) it goes in onErrorResumeNext which handles the error and loads data from the cache. However, if I launch the app with aeroplane mode enabled it goes to onError, which is not supposed to happen, with such string in my logs,

```
D/myLogs: Request error 2 exceptions occurred.  io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred.
```

Here is the code of the request

```
apiContent.getNews("Token " + myHelper.getAuthToken(getActivity()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(NewsObject::getResults)
            .flatMap(news -> {
                Realm.init(getContext());
                Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(realm -> {
                    realm.delete(News.class);
                    realm.insert(news);
                    Log.d("myLogs", "Cached");
                });
                return Observable.just(news);
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                RealmResults<News> results = realm.where(News.class).findAll();
                ArrayList<News> dataNews = new ArrayList<News>();
                dataNews.addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(results));
                Log.d("myLogs", "Error, loading from cache");
                return Observable.just(dataNews);
            })
            .subscribe(new Observer<ArrayList<News>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ArrayList<News> newsObject) {
                    mAdapter.updateData(newsObject);
                    Log.d("myLogs", "Request started");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    Log.d("myLogs", "Request error " + e.getMessage() + " " + e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    Log.d("myLogs", "Request finished");
                }
            });
```

I need to fix it somehow, and also I would appreciate if someone explained me the cause of the problem

The problem is solved. I just replaced `Realm.init(getContext());` before the request call.

Comment: `CompositeException` usually means the error handling function itself crashed while working out the fallback. The code in `onErrorResumeNext` into try-catch and log any potential exception to see what's causing it.

Comment: @akarnokd I got this `Call Realm.init(Context) before calling this method.  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call Realm.init(Context) before calling this method.` So, I got the problem, thanks

Comment: `NewsObject::getResults` does use realm ?

Comment: @crgarridos No, it just returns list of News objects

Comment: The problem is solved

Comment: please, post your solution as answer. it will allow others with the same problem